# Sending a tokio::net::TcpStream to a remote process

Tags: winapi, rust-tokio, windows-socket-api

I'm trying to figure out whether it's possible to send a `tokio::net::TcpStream` or a standard `std::net::TcpStream` to a remote process in Windows.

I figure that I can:

1. Get the raw socket for the stream with `as_raw_socket()`
2. Pass it to `WSADuplicateSocket()`
   3 .Send the `WSAPROTOCOL_INFO` struct to the remote process
3. Pass it to `WSASocket` to create a socket duplicate in the remote process
4. Create a `std::net::TcpStream` by passing the returned SOCKET to `from_raw_socket()`
5. Create a `tokio::net::TcpStream` with `from_std()`

Does that make any sense?

I tried that and I'm able to get a `tokio::net::TcpStream` eventually but then when I try sending data on the remote end I'm getting a `ConnectionReset` error as if the other end (the one which duplicated the socket) has dropped the connection.

Comment: Apparently using `into_raw_socket()` instead of `as_raw_socket()` in step 1 will assume ownership of the stream's socket and prevent the drop implementation for `TcpStream` from closing the connection.